# Вывести дополнительные картинки в анонс новости битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться с проблемой.В битрикс нужно вывести дополнительную картинку в анонс новости.Сейчас вместо картинки отображается ссылка на картинку. Я создала файл result_modifier.php в news.list (файл находится /bitrix/templates/мой_сайт/components/bitrix/news/testimonials/bitrix/news.list/.default) С кодом

```
<? if(count($arResult["MORE_PHOTO"])>0):?>    
    <?foreach($arResult["MORE_PHOTO"] as $PHOTO):?>        
        <? $file = CFile::ResizeImageGet($PHOTO, array('width'=>'327', 'height'=>'183'), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_EXACT, true); ?>        
        <a href="<?=$PHOTO["SRC"]?>" name="more_photo">        
    <img border="0" src="<?=$file["src"]?>" width="<?=$file["width"]?>" height="<?=$file["height"]?>" alt="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>" title="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>" /></a>   
    <?endforeach?><?endif?>
```

И в шаблон компонента поместила код в виде
    0):?> 
     
    '327', 'height'=>'183'), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_EXACT, true); ?>

```
<div class="more_photo"> 

<a href="<?=$PHOTO["SRC"]?>" name="more_photo"><a rel="example_group" href="<?=$PHOTO["SRC"]?>" name="more_photo"  title="<?=(strlen($arResult["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["DESCRIPTION"]) > 0 ? $arResult["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["DESCRIPTION"] : $arResult["NAME"])?>">


<img border="0"  src="<?=$file["src"]?>" width="<?=$file["width"]?>" height="<?=$file["height"]?>" 
alt="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>" title="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>" /> 
</a> 

</div>

<?endforeach?> 
<?endif?>
```

Но картинка так и не появилась и в место неё так и остаётся ссылка.

Answer (score 1):

Есть очень много причин, почему именно это не работает.

Нельзя просто так обращаться в компоненте к "MORE_PHOTO". В Битриксе в элементах инфоблока нет такого поля.
Битрикс использует его в компонентах каталога и в предоставляемых примерах создаётся инфоблок у которого есть одноимённое свойство в котором хранится список дополнительных картинок. И в компоненте каталога для простоты доступа значения эти выносят непосредственно в массив с полями элемента инфоблока.

Но это справедливо только для каталога! В новостях такого свойства по умолчанию нет. И компоненты новостей не обрабатывают никак это свойство.

---

> if(count($arResult["MORE_PHOTO"])>0)

это условие никогда не выполнится потому что в компоненте news.list в массиве $arResult нет элемента "MORE_PHOTO" и count от него никогда не превысит нуля.

В массиве $arResult в есть элемент "ITEMS" ($arResult["ITEMS"]), в котором храниться массив элементов инфоблока. эту проверку нужно проводить в каждом элементе отдельно.

---

```
<? if(count($arResult["MORE_PHOTO"])>0):?>    
    <?foreach($arResult["MORE_PHOTO"] as $PHOTO):?>        
        <? $file = CFile::ResizeImageGet($PHOTO, array('width'=>'327', 'height'=>'183'), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_EXACT, true); ?>        
        <a href="<?=$PHOTO["SRC"]?>" name="more_photo">        
            <img border="0" src="<?=$file["src"]?>" width="<?=$file["width"]?>" height="<?=$file["height"]?>" alt="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>" title="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>" />
        </a>   
    <?endforeach?>
<?endif?>
```

В приведённом Вами коде в  **result_modifier.php** вы пытаетесь вывести картинки со ссылками. Вы не можете это делать там. Файл **result_modifier.php** используется для приведения данных, лежащих в $arResult к нужному виду.

---

В шаблоне Вы повторяете свою ошибку и обращаетесь напрямую к **$arResult** вместо того, чтобы обращаться к конкретному элементу.

---

### Что Вам нужно делать.

1. Создайте свойство для хранения дополнительных картинок в инфоблоке или убедитесь что оно есть
2. Убедитесь что при вызове компонента, вы указали это свойство в качестве доступного.
3. В файле result_modifier.php по значениям свойства получите данные о файле и сохраниете их в соответствующий элемент в массиве arResult
4. Выведите их в шаблоне
5. Сбросьте кеш перед проверкой